# How to ensure environment variables sourced while in venv context are not acessible out of it?

Tags: python

I know it's possible to create a venv

```bash
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

Than create a `.env` file and fill it with with some variable:

```
export PASSWORD="123"
```

Than set the variables to you enviroment:

```bash
source .env
```

And create a `script.py` file that accesses your variable:

```py
import os
print(os.environ['PASSWORD'])
```

execute it with env activated

```
python script.py
```

It successfully prints `123`.

However, if you exit the venv with:

```
deactivate
```

And execute the script again withing the same terminal, it still works, printing `123`.

However, when trying to execute script from a new terminal (non sourced into venv and .env), finally an error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(os.environ['PASSCODE'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PASSWORD'
```

It seems to me that the variable isn't in fact setted "in the virtual environment" but in the terminal instance. As it's possible to access it even after deactivating the venv.

How exactly does setting environment variables in a `venv` works, and is it possible to truthfully make them only accessible while inside the `venv`?

Comment: Your shell environment is completely separate from your Python virtual environment.  They are not related.  Perhaps you should open a new shell (by typing `bash`) before starting your venv.  Then, when you deactivate, you can Ctrl-D to back out of the new shell.

Comment: @TimRoberts If they are completely unrelated, how can a variable setted while sourced in the vm still be accessible after using deactivate?

Comment: Virtual environment only changes the python related environment variables & the PATH - not everything in your shell. So everything else in your shell should work as expected even inside a virtualenv

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks @rdas! Is there a way to source enclosed customized environment variables while inside venv?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean by "enclosed customized environment variables"? You can simply `unset` those custom variables when you don't need them

Comment: @rdas I mean, as you said python related environment variables are separated from OS environment variables when using a virtualenv. I would like to create my own environment variables, that behave like python related environment variables while in a venv

Comment: Then do what I said.  Start a new bash, and activate the venv within that shell.  Just make it a two step process to start.  Then you don't even need to `deactivate` -- just press Ctrl-D to exit the shell, and your venv goes away as well.

Comment: @TimRoberts I know it works but i'm concerned about the security implications of the variables that should be available only in the venv to be available in the whole terminal window

Comment: Check the script `venv/bin/activate` to see how it works. It's just saving the variables it will override in other variables & then overrding them. The `deactivate` function just undoes that.